# How to choose between multi column indexes and single column indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have one table called `users` with a PRIMARY key on `users.zbid`. However, all `SELECT` queries run on it include the `WHERE` clause `cid='$cid' AND zbid='$zbid'`. Should I add an index for `cid` or a multi-column index for `cid,zbid` ? I know the `WHERE` clause on `cid` seems redundant as `zbid` is `PRIMARY`, but it's mainly there as a precautionary step, each `cid` designates a different forum, and in case something went wrong I don't want every forum to be effected.

Secondly, I have another table called `notifications`. The only query that is run on this table uses the where clause `cid='$cid' AND zbid='$zbid'`, should I add them both as individual indexes or just one? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have primary key on `users.zdib`, there is no need for composite index (mysql will use the existing index on `zdib`)
2. If `cid` is used in a similar way as in your first table, no need to have composite index, it should be enough just an index on `zdib`. Otherwise, make it on 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think the multi-column index will perform better.

cid,zbid will require 1 seek

having 2 indices will require 2 seeks

Answer (score 0):

In the first case MySQL will use the PRIMARY_KEY (it doesn't matter what other AND's you have).

In the second case you should add both of them in one index (assuming the columns are non-unique) that will leave fewer results to filter afterwards.

You should also check [covering indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index). But i don't think those will make a difference in your case.