# explain() in Mongodb: differences between "nscanned" and "nscannedObjects"

Tags: mongodb

I cannot get the exact difference between "nscanned" and "nscannedObjects" in the Mongodb's explain query output.

On [MongoDB Explain documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) I can read:

> **nscanned** Number of items (documents or index entries) examined. Items
>   might be objects or index keys. If a "covered index" is involved,
>   nscanned may be higher than nscannedObjects.
>
> **nscannedObjects** Number of documents scanned.

What's the different between these two fields?
And more specific what does exactly mean when I have a query, which uses a BtreeCursor (an index), and these two fields have two different values, for example:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1_b_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 5,
    "nscannedObjects" : 5,
    "nscanned" : 9, 
    (...)
}
```

I know what a "[covered index"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index) is.
I would like to understand exactly what the query did in the example above.
Did it pass through ("scanned") 9 elements (nscanned = 9), where all of them are index entries and read ("examined") the value of only 5 of them (nscannedObjects = 5) to produce the result set?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This means that :
The query returned 5 documents - `n`
scanned 9 documents from the index - `nscanned`
and then read 5 full documents from the collection - `nscannedObjects`

Similar example is given at :
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain

Answer (score 1):

if "cursor" is Index ==> nscanned = no. of index scanned
else if "cursor" is FullTableScan ==> nscanned = no. of document scanned

nscannedObjects ==> No. of document scanned

when querying, try to minimise all count, i.e. nscanned and nscannedObjects both are minimum means your query *should* run faster!