# Duplicate UniqueIdentifier Indexes

Tags: sql-server-2005, database-indexes

I think my understanding of indexes in SQL Server 2005 (and maybe all indexes??) is flawed, please educate me.

We have a table with say 5 columns:

```
Id  |  ProductId | OrderId | PriceId | Approved | Price
---------------------------------------------------------
1   |  2545      | 32345   | 224     |      1   |  150.00
```

The table has 30 million rows (if it matters there are actually around 30 columns in the actual table).

The `Id` columns are all `UniqueIdentifer`, so the posts around the fact that it might not be redundant if one of them is a large field don't seem to be relevant.

If I add an index on the column `ProductID`.

```
CREATE INDEX "ProductIndex" ON "dummy_table" (
   "ProductId"
)
```

Then add another index on `ProductId` AND `OrderId` AND `PriceId`

```
CREATE INDEX "ProductAndOrderIndex" ON "dummy_table" (
   "ProductId",
   "OrderId",
   "PriceId"
)
```

Is the first index redundant, i.e. the SQL Server planner should revert to using the second one and the performance be as good?

This question has arisen due to the fact that removing the first index causes a massive performance decrease (10 seconds for a process has gone to 2 and half minutes). I've narrowed it down to that specific index, so the next thing would be to trace all the SQL, but that's going to be a big task that I don't want to do unless I have to.

Comment: Why are you using `"identifiers"` that make your `"tables"`, `"columns"` and `"indexes"` look like string literals? They're not needed here, but IMHO it is much more readable to use `[square brackets]` when necessary.

Comment: My bad... I'll get those changed to Guids

Comment: @AaronBertrand: The ANSI object delimiter character is the `"`, so isn't wrong. But, I have to say, I use only `[]` (when necessary).

Comment: @Martin: In terms of space used by these two indices, if all `%Id` columns are `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`s, if this table has a unique clustered index (`Id`) and if the table has 30 million rows then the differences is aprox. 926 MB (not Mb).

Comment: @Bogdan nowhere did I say it was "wrong" - just less readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of the index on `ProductId` the query optimizer will likely use the index on `ProductId`, `OrderId` and `PriceId`.  Either index will contain more entries per page than the table rows, hence they reduce I/O required.

The first index will contain more entries per page and fewer duplicates on `ProductId` than the second index.  That makes it much more efficient for lookups by `ProductId`.  If the query uses `OrderId` and/or `PriceId`, even if they are only output columns, then the query optimizer may still find the second index to be more efficient.  (See [covered index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index).)

Look at the execution plan for the query.  It will show how the indexes are used and the number of I/O operations performed.  That should clear up most of the mysteries.