# Using a covering index to select records for a certain day

Tags: mysql, performance, datetime, indexing

I would like to run these queries:

`select url from weixin_kol_status where created_at>'2015-12-11 00:00:00' and created_at<'2015-12-11 23:59:59';`

and

`select url from weixin_kol_status where userid in ('...') and created_at>'2015-12-11 00:00:00' and created_at<'2015-12-11 23:59:59';`

… using this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `weixin_kol_status` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `text` text,
  `attitudes_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `readcount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reposts_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comments_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ext_data` text,
  `is_topline` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_business` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_url` (`url`(255)),
  KEY `idx_userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `idx_name` (`screen_name`),
  KEY `idx_created_at` (`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=328727437 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


rows = 328727437;
```

The queries take several minutes.  How can I optimize the queries? How can I use the covering index?

The execution plans are:

```
explain select id from weixin_kol_status where created_at>='2015-12-11 00:00:00' and created_at<='2015-12-11 23:59:59'\G;
    *************************** 1. row ***************************
               id: 1
      select_type: SIMPLE
            table: weixin_kol_status
             type: range
    possible_keys: idx_created_at
              key: idx_created_at
          key_len: 5
              ref: NULL
             rows: 1433704
            Extra: Using where; Using index
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
explain select id from weixin_kol_status where created_at='2015-12-11 00:00:00'\G; 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: weixin_kol_status
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_created_at
          key: idx_created_at
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but why the first query `Extra: Using where; Using index`, and the second query `Extra: Using index`. Did the first query not use the covering index?

Comment: Since this has now become a specific question about how to use covering indexes, it is no longer a request for your code to be reviewed.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use the covering index?

Do you know what a [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index) is?  It's an index that contains all the columns that you need for your query.  So for

> ```
> select url from weixin_kol_status where created_at>'2015-12-11 00:00:00' and created_at<'2015-12-11 23:59:59';
> ```

the minimum covering index would be something like

```
      KEY `idx_created_url` (`created_at`, `url`)
```

And for

> ```
> select url from weixin_kol_status where userid in ('...') and created_at>'2015-12-11 00:00:00' and created_at<'2015-12-11 23:59:59';
> ```

the minimum covering index might be

```
      KEY `idx_created_user_url` (`created_at`, `userid`, `url`)
```

which would also cover the first query or

```
      KEY `idx_user_created_url` (`userid`, `created_at`, `url`)
```

which wouldn't work for the first query but may better optimize the second.

You might have to write out `url(512)` instead of just `url`.  `VARCHAR` columns don't index well.  If you get an error about the indexed values being too wide, you may not be able to use a covering index with this query.

A covering index is helpful because it can answer everything from the index in memory without going to the table on disk.  Since memory is faster than disk, it has the effect of speeding up the query.  Of course, if your index is paged out, you will still have to load it from disk.  So if you're memory bound, this may not help.

Note that a query will only use one index per table, so the separate indexes on each column won't cover either query.  You need a compound index to cover all the needed columns at once.

As a side note, I think that your `>` and `<` should be `>=` and `<=` respectively.  Probably won't make much difference, but you seem to be skipping two seconds a day.

Comment: A secondary index paged in/out of memory just as the data.  That is, the index won't necessarily "answer everything from the index in memory".

Comment: A "covering" index would be nice.  But `url` is too big to be in any index.

Answer (score 0):

**Several issues**

- `UNIQUE(url(255))` constrains the *first 255* characters to be unique; this was probably not desired.
- If you need to force uniqueness of a long string (`url`), add another column with `MD5(url)` and make that column `UNIQUE`.  (Or something like that.)
- There is a limit of 767 bytes per column in an index, so if you try to create `INDEX(created_at, url)`, you get `INDEX(created_at, url(255))`, which is *not* covering, since not all of `url` is in the index.
- Both `EXPLAINs` are useless for this discussion since they are not using the `SELECTs` you are asking about.  In the first, it says `Using index` because you say `SELECT id`; the actual query is `SELECT url`.  This makes a *big* difference in performance.
- You have a very large table.  I see no way for `PARTITIONing` to help with speed.
- This is a better way to express a 1-day `WHERE`:

  ```
       created_at >= '2015-12-11'
   AND created_at  < '2015-12-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  ```

**To speed it up**

Here is an off-the-wall technique that should help both queries.  Instead of

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `idx_created_at` (`created_at`)
```

Do it this way:

```
PRIMARY KEY(created_at, id),
INDEX(id)
```

That will "cluster" on `created_at`, thereby cutting down on I/O significantly, especially for the first `SELECT`.  Yes, it is OK for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` to be just `INDEXed`, not `UNIQUE` nor `PRIMARY KEY`.

Caution:  To make the change will take hours and a lot of disk space.