# Need to improve performance query a table with millions of rows - SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, hikaricp

This query on an audit trail table starts slowing down once the load increases in performance testing (reads and inserts) and I've done what I can with indexing. With this query and these tables and indexes, what more can I do?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mod2] (
  [id] [int] IDENTITY,
  [userId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [epochTime] [bigint] NOT NULL,
  [forecastId] [int] NOT NULL,
  [description] [char](12) NOT NULL,
  [auxText] [text] NULL,
  [auxDate] [date] NULL
);


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mod2] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_mod2 PRIMARY KEY(ID);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mod2]  WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_mod2_forecastId] FOREIGN KEY([forecastId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[forecast] ([id]);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mod2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_mod2_forecastId];

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mod2]  WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_mod2_userId] FOREIGN KEY([userId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[user] ([id]);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mod2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_mod2_userId];

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_modification_auxDate ON [dbo].[mod2] (auxDate ASC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_modification_epochTime ON [dbo].[mod2] (epochTime ASC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_modification_description ON [dbo].[mod2] (description ASC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_modification_forecastId ON [dbo].[mod2] (forecastId ASC);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_modification_userId ON [dbo].[mod2] (userId ASC);
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT name, epochTime, auxDate 
    FROM mod2 WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN [user] ON [user].id = mod2.userId 
    WHERE forecastId = ? AND description = ? AND auxDate = ?
```

This is a legacy system and it was crawling before I put these indexes on it and changed the `description` field from `VARCHAR` to `CHAR`

The forecast and user `id` fields are `INT` and indexed similarly.

Comment: You might also consider changing the datatype of auxText from text to varchar(max). it isn't going to help this query but the text datatype has been deprecated in favor of varchar(max) for over a decade now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do here.

One is to ensure there is a clustered index on `user` for its `id` field (probably there is, but making sure won't hurt).

The individual indexes you put in are not great - in particular given the query pattern you have shown - either non of them would be used (as they do not contain the full data), or some of them might be used and then the full table will be refered to in order to pick out the remaining data required to fulfill the query.

For this particular query, for `mod2`, I'd likely add an index on `userId` with it [covering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index) `forecastId`, `description` and `auxDate` - this way the index contains all the data required to fulfil the query (on the `mod2` side).

Comment: @Adam - consider removing your one field indexes in favour of less indexes that cover more.

Comment: OK. So if do that, and then have another query which doesn't use `auxDate` in the `WHERE` clause, should I create a second covered index for it or will the original covered index suffice, even though it includes `auxDate`?

Comment: @Adam - if the other query still uses the other covered fields, the index will likely still be used, so another index may not be needed.

Comment: Checked the [user].[id] column is indexed with a PK clustered index, and created the index (edited your answer) and ran some performance tests which show the duration dropped by 2/3, which is nice. It is significantly still the slowest operation in the app though, which is puzzling because the other 2 main end-points do writes to that table but are twice as quick now (previously 5 times quicker). Does that still suggest a problem or am I going to have to live with this?

Comment: @Adam - check the query plan, see what is and isn't using indexes, what is scanning (good) vs seeking (not so good). Consider that inserting **one** row vs going through millions will of course be worse. When you say slowest, by what factor?

Comment: No scans, just seeks! Currently playing with index. Does ASC/DESC help much?

Comment: ASC/DESC just describes the order these are saved in the index, though the closer that is to the actual query requirements, the better.

Comment: I had to delete the other indexes before SQL Server would use my new covered index. And now it does, but I see it's doing a Seek, not a Scan. See my answer, although I don't see what else I can do.

Comment: At least it _is_ using the index. How much slower is the query than others?

Comment: need to get the sql query logging with log4jdbc, but spring boot won't let me so I'm leaving it like this for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IXmod2_user_desc_forecast_auxdate 
ON [dbo].[mod2] (userId, forecastId, description, auxDate DESC);
```

and the query plans looks like this:

```
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[id]) OPTIMIZED)
       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([MyDB].[dbo].[user].[id], [Expr1006]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
       |    |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([MyDB].[dbo].[user].  [PK_user]), ORDERED FORWARD)
       |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[IX_mod2_user_desc_forecast_auxdate]), SEEK:([MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[userId]=[MyDB].[dbo].[user].[id] AND [MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[forecastId]=(40357) AND [MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[description]='SAVE' AND [MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[auxDate]='2017-01-31') ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[PK_mod2]), SEEK:([MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[id]=[MyDB].[dbo].[mod2].[id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
```