# Replace index scan on index seek in SQL Server SELECT query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

The first query works fine with index seek (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1XMM_YeW):

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MessageLast c
    WHERE c.Stat_Date >= '2017-04-25' 
                AND c.Stat_Date <= '2017-04- 26' 
                AND c.partner_id IN (111294, 100001, 111295, 111435, 111296, 118155,111498, 118397);
```

Second query bad with idex scan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1uvEdFgZ):

```
CREATE TABLE #t (partner_id Int primary key clustered);
INSERT INTO  #t(partner_id) 
values  (111294), (100001), (111295), (111435), (111296), (118155),(111498), (118397);

SELECT *
FROM dbo.MessageLast c
    where  c.Stat_Date >= '2017-04-25' 
                and c.Stat_Date <= '2017-04- 26' 
                and c.partner_id in (select partner_id from #t);
```

Third query with EXISTS also is bad (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ryk3IntgZ):

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   dbo.MessageLast c with (forceseek)

 WHERE  c.Stat_Date >= '2017-04-25'
        and c.Stat_Date <= '2017-04-26'
        and exists(select
                       * 
                   from  #d as d where  c.partner_id = d.partner_id)
```

Changing temp table `#t` on table variable or standard table doesn't help - same plan like the second query.

Simple demo script:

```
create table _tBig (
  dt Date
, id1 Int
, id2 Int
, id3 Int
, id4 Int
, txt Varchar(500)
) 
create clustered index PK_tBig  on _tBig (id4,dt)



--truncate table _tBig

declare @i Int = 1
set nocount on
while @i < 10000
begin
    insert  into _tBig with (tablock)
            (dt
           , id1
           , id2
           , id3
           , id4
           , txt
            )
    select top (1000)
            DateAdd(day, Rand() * 365 + 1, GetDate())
          , Row_Number() over (order by O.[object_id])
          , Rand() * 10000000 + 1
          , Rand() * 10000000 + 1
          , Rand() * 10000000 + 1
          , NewId()
    from    sys.all_objects O

    set @i += 1

end 


create table _tId (id1 Int)



--truncate table _tId

insert  into _tId
        (id1
        )
select top (5)
        Row_Number() over (order by O.[object_id])
from    sys.all_objects O



select  *
from    _tBig as tb
where   tb.dt >= '20170517'
        and tb.dt < '20170519'
        and tb.id1 in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

create index IX_Big on _tBig (dt,id1)

select  *
from    _tBig as tb
inner join _tId as ti on ti.id1 = tb.id1
where   tb.dt >= '20170517'
        and tb.dt < '20170519'


create index IX_Big2 on _tBig (id1,dt)

select  *
from    _tBig as tb
inner join _tId as ti on ti.id1 = tb.id1
where   tb.dt >= '20170517'
        and tb.dt < '20170519'

--drop table dbo._tBig
--drop table dbo._tId
```

Comment: Your temporary table has no indexes, so only a full table scan can work. Beyond that, Table variables don't perform faster than tables. In fact, they can be far slower if used as TVPs. A TVP is empty when the query is compiled, so there are no statistics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because index is not covering: you are selecting ALL fields in table.

When index does not cover the query sql server shoud do 2 steps:

1) Index seek to find PK values (and included columnsd) that mathed predicate

2) Key lookup (seek in clustered index) **for each row** to find values of column which was not included in index.

Therefore in some cases query optimizer decides that full table scan is faster than these two steps.

You can replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT dt` (make index covering) and you receive an index seek. Here is more info: [What is a Covered Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index)

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MessageLast c
        JOIN #t t on c.partner_id = t.partner_id
where  c.Stat_Date >= '2017-04-25' 
                and c.Stat_Date <= '2017-04- 26'
```