# Sql Server - Index not being used

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, database-performance

After running the following query:

```
SELECT [hour], count(*) as hits, avg(elapsed)
FROM myTable
WHERE [url] IS NOT NULL and floordate >= '2017-05-01'
group by [hour]
```

the execution plan is basically a clustered Index Scan on the PK (int, auto-increment, 97% of the work)

The thing is: `URL` has a index on it (regular index because i'm always searching for a exact match), `floordate` also has an index...

Why are they not being used? How can i speed up this query?

PS: table is 70M items long and this query takes about 9 min to run

**Edit 1**
If i don't use (select or filter) a column on my index, will it still be used? Usually i also filter-for/group-by `clientId` (approx 300 unique across the db) and `hour` (24 unique)...

Comment: what about the columns `hour` and `Elapsed`, if these columns are not included in the indexes you have mentioned query will need to lookup in the clustered index to get these values.

Comment: The indexes on individual columns don't cover the whole query (`hour` and `elapsed` will still need to be looked up), and if most rows have `url` `NOT NULL` the index on `url` isn't useful at all. So it all comes down to how many rows the engine estimates will be covered by `floordate >= '2017-05-01'` and whether clustered index lookups will beat scanning it directly. If your statistics are out of date, this estimate may be wildly off. Try updating those before you do anything else (the next logical step would be to `INCLUDE` columns in that index).

Comment: You can replace count(*) by count(1) and it may help to improve some time..

Comment: Can you add table schema along with indexes

Comment: What @JeroenMostert said. Also, look at the column order in your index. Based on how you're querying, effectively without url, your column order should be floordate, then url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Covered Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index)

Comment: What @JeroenMostert said. Also, From perspective of performance, "Eliminate as many useless rows as quickly as possible" is the general idea. If most of your data in url column is not null, the index on url is useless to narrow down the rows to work with. 
Database index optimization is not always an easy task, an index could speed up a certain query, but could confuse sql server for other queries.
For your query as it stands, I'd suggest a separate index on the floordate column and include the hour and elapsed columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, two things affect how SQL Server will choose an index.

1. How selective is the index.  A higher selectivity is better.  NULL/NOT NULL filters generally have a very low selectivity.
2. Are all of the columns in the index, also known as a covering index.

In your example, if the index cannot cover the query, SQL will have to look up the other column values against the base table.  If your URL/Floordate combination is not selective enough, SQL may determine it is cheaper to scan the base table rather than do an expensive lookup from the non-clustered index to the base table for a large number of rows.

Without knowing anything else about your schema, I'd recommend an index with the following columns:

```
floordate, url, hour; include elapsed
```

Date ranges scans are generally more selective than a NULL/NOT NULL test.  Moving Floordate to the front may make this index more desirable for this query.  If SQL determines the query is good for Floordate and URL, the Hour column can be used for the Group By action.  Since Elapsed is included, this index can cover the query completely.

You can include ClientID after hour to see if that helps your other query as well.

As long as an index contains all of the columns to resolve the query, it is a candidate for use, even if there is no filtering needed.  Generally speaking, a non-clustered index is skinnier than the base table, requiring less IO than scanning the full width base table.