# Query on columns (x, z) for a multi-column index (x, y, z)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  x some_type_1,
  y some_type_2,
  z some_type_3,
  PRIMARY KEY (x, y, z)
);
```

Now I want to execute this query efficiently:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE x = ? AND z = ?;
```

Is the (primary-key) index `(x, y, z)` enough in this case, or should I create a separate index `(x, z)`?

Answer (score 1):

That existing index on primary key should be enough in this case since with `PRIMARY KEY (x, y, z)` what you essentially have is a `Covering Index`. See [What is a Covered Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137/what-is-a-covered-index)

Answer (score 1):

The primary key index is *sufficient* for the query.  However, it is not *optimal*.

In order for Postgres to use the index, it needs to scan all the entries in the index where `x = ?` in order to find the matching values for `z`.  This might be good enough performance.

But, the optimal index for the query would be `(x, z, y)`, because this covers the query *and* satisfies the `where` clause efficiently.  The next best index is `(x, z)`, because it covers the `where` clause.  The existing primary key index will be used partially for the `where` clause (assuming statistics on the table say that an index should be used).